# Event with mouseclick on picturebox ptrEinstein

Tags: c#

I am creating a paintball game in C# windows form application. I want it so when you left-click on the target(ptrEinstein) which is a picturebox, it comes up with a messagebox. Here is my form1 below.

```
namespace AmazingPaintball
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random positionX = new Random();
    Random positionY = new Random();
    Target einstein;
    int count = 0;
    Paintballs pBalls = new Paintballs();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Point point = new Point(positionX.Next(0, 638), positionY.Next(0, 404));
        einstein = new Target(point);
        ptrEinstein.Location = point;           
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pBalls.paint(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ptrEinstein.Location = einstein.Move(e.KeyData);
        pictureBox1.Update();
        pictureBox1.Refresh();           
    }




    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        pBalls.add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();            



        if (ptrEinstein.Location == ??)
        {

            stopwatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");                
        }
        count++;
    }        

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }       
}
```

}

In picturebox1_click is where the problem appears to be. I want it so that when I click ptrEinstein, the message box shows up. Please let me know if there is not enough info. Thank You

Comment: please provide info on what is the exact error or issue. and what is the objective you want to achieve

Comment: Do you mean that there are __two__ pictureboxes? If so they have __two distinct__ MouseClick events you'll want to script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure that you have a second picturebox named "ptrEinstein", then you should write the line below in **ptrEinstein_MouseClick** method, instead of writing it in pictureBox1_MouseClick.

```
MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");
```

so that message box appears when you click ptrEinstein. To automatically add the right method:

In Design page, select ptrEinstein picture and click lightning symbol from its Properties and then double click MouseClick , it will add the necessary empty method for you, then you can add the messagebox inside. It will look like:

```
private void ptrEinstein_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
       MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit 
    }
```